# Aurelia and System.js production build

Tags: javascript, aurelia, systemjs

I am maintaining an existing Aurelia project that apparently wasn't created with Aurelia CLI.

I need to create a **production build** but am not being able with the current configuration. The development build works just fine, but, as expected, downloads a lot of code to user machine.

After running `gulp prod` (gulpfile listed below), I get two JS files: `app-build-{revnumber}.js` and `vendor-build-{revnumber}.js`, but Aurelia keeps trying to load the `main.js` file.

[image: Error loading main.js]

I tried building the `main.js` together (commented code in `gulpfile.js`), but had no success - only vendor bundle is loaded:

[image: Only vendor bundle is loaded]

Here are my config files:

**config.js**

```
System.config({
  baseURL: "/www",
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  transpiler: "babel",
  babelOptions: {
    "stage": 0,
    "optional": [
      "runtime",
      "optimisation.modules.system"
    ]
  },
  paths: {
    "*": "src/*",
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*",
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*"
  },
  map: { /* mappings */ }
});
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var bundler = require('aurelia-bundler');
var image = image = require('gulp-image');
var replace = require('gulp-replace');
var gulpsync = require('gulp-sync')(gulp);

var config = {
  force: true,
  baseURL: '.',
  configPath: './config.js',
  bundles: {
    // "dist/main": {
    //   includes: [
    //     '[main.js]'
    //   ],
    //   options: {
    //     inject: true,
    //     minify: false,
    //     rev: false
    //   }
    // },
    "dist/app-build": {
      includes: [
        '[**/*.js]',
        '**/*.html!text',
        '**/*.css!text'
      ],
      options: {
        inject: true,
        minify: true,
        rev: true
      }
    },
    "dist/vendor-build": {
      includes: [ /* all external modules */ ],
      options: {
        inject: true,
        minify: true,
        rev: true
      }
    }
  }
};

gulp.task("bundle", function () {
  return bundler.bundle(config)
    .then(function () {
      gulp.src('config.js')
        .pipe(replace('dist/', ''))
        .pipe(replace('src', 'dist'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(''));
    });
});

gulp.task("unbundle",
  function () {
    return bundler.unbundle(config)
      .then(function () {
        gulp.src('config.js')
          .pipe(replace('dist', 'src'))
          .pipe(gulp.dest(''));
      });
  });

gulp.task("image-bundle",
  function () {
    gulp.src('./src/media/*')
      .pipe(image())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/media'));
  });

gulp.task("files-bundle", function () {
  return gulp
    .src('./src/style/material.woff2')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/style'));
});

gulp.task('prod', gulpsync.sync(['unbundle', 'bundle', 'image-bundle', 'files-bundle']));

gulp.task('dev', gulpsync.sync(['unbundle']));
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body aurelia-app="main">
    <script src="www/jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
    <script src="www/config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('aurelia-bootstrapper');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of little adjustments, I solved the `main.js` issue.

It seems like System.js looks for the dependency in the bundle and, if not found, it hits the network. Here's what I did to fix my bundle:

1. Consolidated `dist/` folder as the bundle source

   In `config.js`, set the path of `*` to `dist/*` and don't modify it in any Gulp task.
   [image: from src to dist]
2. Before the bundle task runs, I copy all contents from `src/` to `dist/`
3. In the `dist/app-build` bundle, I added the option `depCache: true`. It does not work when `false` (gives the error of `main.js` not found), but I don't really know why.

The added/modified Gulp tasks:

```
// deletes all files in the output path
gulp.task('clean', ['unbundle'], function () {
  return gulp.src(['dist/'])
    .pipe(vinylPaths(del));
});

gulp.task('copy', function () {
  return gulp.src(['src/**/*'])
    .pipe(gulpCopy('dist/', { prefix: 1 }));
});

gulp.task("bundle", sync(['clean', 'copy']), function () {
  return bundler.bundle(config);
});

gulp.task("unbundle", function () {
  return bundler.unbundle(config);
});
```